# Yet another kernel_task high CPU usage question

Tags: macos, mac-mini, kernel

I have a headless Quad-Core Mac mini living in the storage cupboard and in the last week or so which possibly coincides with updating to El Capitan has began having the problem, 600% usage from boot.

I've read all the posts out there about how to fix this:

```
system_profiler -detailLevel mini | grep "Model Identifier:" | sed "s/^.*: //"
```

Eventually yields **Macmini6,2** so I then:

```
ls /System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources | grep "Macmini"
```

Which provides the following:

Macmini3_1.plist
Macmini4_1.plist
Macmini5_1.plist
Macmini5_2.plist
Macmini5_3.plist

Meaning my model's property list file is not present and as such I can't proceed with what has been for most a highly successful fix by moving/deleting or create an in-place backup followed by a reboot.

It's exactly the same outcome with an identical model also running El Capitan that lives on a shelf on my TV stand in my living room which acts as one of my Plex clients whilst also hosting my Windows 10 development VM via Fusion 8.  I'd be devastated if it started happening to that machine.  The performance would be unbearable.

So without a property list file how do I move forward?  Any help gratefully appreciated.  The headless machine runs several web apps very smoothly and has done so since I bought it.  No new apps have been installed that may cause this.

Thanks,
Lee.

Comment: What do you mean "headless"? Did you somehow remove the GUI, or do you simply mean you ssh into the macs and never use the GUI?

Comment: If you've aren't sure what the term headless means with regards to computers and technology you're either a noob looking to learn or something else ... if the former then yes as in I mostly SSH to manage and configure it, I use the web apps it runs via a browser and occasionally have to use Apple's Screen Sharing which totally sucks in terms of performance, connection time in particular, compared M$'s RDP.

Comment: "A headless server is a computing device without a local interface" - [link](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/headless-server). While we could quibble over whether the fact that your server has a GUI whether you use it or not makes it count as "headless", it would be more constructive to just move forward. Have you tried emptying the directory (I usually just move it to another place)? These property list files are usually generated at boot or by a daemon, copying them elsewhere as a back up and rebooting has fixed many issues for me.

Comment: No I ha not considered emptying the entire directory.  I'll try later when I have more time.  Thanks you for the suggestion @agentroadkill.